# Laravel telescope assets url is generated with https scheme instead of http

Tags: laravel, laravel-telescope

I am trying to integrate laravel telescope in my laravel(9) app which is only serving as an api.There is no fornt-end. The app is running in a docker container, port 80 of the container exposed via port 82 on the host machine. So effectively the backend is accessed at `http://localhost:82`

After pulling in the telescope package and following the offical documentation for local only installaiton, when i visit the dashboard at `http://localhost:82/telescope` i can see the front end is broken. When i looked at the networks tab I can see the assets are failing to be loaded from the backend, because the asset urls are using `https` instaed of `http`:

```
https://localhost:82/vendor/telescope/app.css?id=b89676ee10846bfd767c6836074db724
https://localhost:82/vendor/telescope/app.js?id=1abbba05aec248b088a0ae6e3e22d2bc
https://localhost:82/vendor/telescope/favicon.ico
```

I tried the following in the register(also the boot) method of `AppServiceProvider`

```
        if (config('app.env') === 'local') {
            URL::forceScheme('http');
        }

        if (env('APP_ENV') === 'local') {
            $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', false);
        }
```

If i visit those assets with http they load.
How can i solve this? What am i doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: add your .env configs

Comment: `.env` should be `APP_URL=http://localhost:82`

Comment: @OMiShah @Povilas My .env already has `APP_URL=http://localhost:82`

Comment: I found out about the ASSET_URL env variable, which was missing in my .env file. I added that and it solved the issue. But the documentation says that variable is needed only if the assets are deployed to a domain separate from the app! Is that misleading?